# PostgreSQL 9.4 & 12.1, loses locks after SQL error

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, odbc, postgresql-9.4

We use PostgreSQL in an application which supports ad hoc queries

Let's take following example with PostgreSQL:

The application uses a table named "ENT001" and is defined with Cautious Locking which means when user starts to modify a record, the record will be immediately locked, so that a second user won't be able to modify the same record until the lock is released.

After the record is modified (so locked), in the same application session, a SQL statement as following is executed:
"select count ( * )  froAAAm ent001"

Notice the wrongly spelled keyword froAAAm, this is an syntax error.

With current PostgreSQL, after executing above SQL statement, the lock on the modified record is released by the PostgreSQL server, so a second application session is able to modify the same record, this is NOT what we expect. This problem occurs only with PostgreSQL and not with Oracle or MS SQL Server.

What we see is, PostgreSQL aborts the transaction on an SQL error, leading to the release of all the locks associated within the transaction.

Is this described issue with PostgreSQL a bug or is this by design?

We used the following api call to handle the SQL

```
result = SQLExecDirectW(sqlStatement, statementText, SQL_NTS);
```

and replaces this with

```
result = SQLPrepareW(sqlStatement, statementText, SQL_NTS);
...
result = SQLExecute(sqlStatement);
```

This seems to work, however the behavior is somewhat different in multiple transactions in a short time. SQLPrepareW returns sometimes:"The prepared statement already exists" or an error which tells us that PostgreSQL is still busy. Sorry for the last error, I have no details yet.

Is this described issue with PostgreSQL a bug or is this by design?

Comment: If you have an error in your transaction, the whole transaction needs to be rolled back  which terminates the transaction and thus relases all locks. This is how transactions are defined. If you want to deal with an error for a single statement you will need to guard that statement with a Savepoint

Comment: With SQL Server sometimes it aborts the transaction on error. Other times it doesn't. I usually set `XACT_ABORT` on to ensure that it always does